# How to link javascript in html

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating browser based video editing tool. I want a user to first download a ~70mb javascript file and store it somewhere on his computer. I want to link that file when my website is opened. How can I achieve that.

**EDIT**

What i meant is that there are various files like js1.js,js2.js... all sums upto 70mb . So i will offer a zip folder to download and only link js1 or js2 file etc depending on the effects user wish to apply

Comment: That's how browsers work out of the box.

Comment: Well you can try to use local storage for that but you still need some configuration to access the hard drive from the web. Modern browsers got that secured

Answer (score 0):

That is actually done automatically. Once you add a `<script>` tag with a link to a local js file (also stored on the server) the file is loaded automatically.
See [HTML <script> src Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp) for more information on that.

You can only reference to js files on the server. Files on the server could look like this:

- index.html
- somefancyjsfile.js

You can then reference from inside your html file to the js file via the `<script>` tag.
I'm not sure though if the size is not a bit too much...

Comment: well how do I get the path of user's local file system

Comment: You can't access files on the clients filesystem. You can only provide the js files via the server.

Answer (score 0):

i am sorry to inform you but i think there is something really wrong with what you are trying to do.

A "solution" would be to just cache the javascript on the user's browser so any subsequent requests parse the cache instead of requesting the resource again from the server.

You should know however that if you are in need to download ~70mb of a javascript file you are doing something wrong. I have a whole web app project that when published the total size is around 60mb, all files required to properly run included, and its a damn big codebase in there.

I find it very hard to believe there is ever a need for a single javascript file to be that big, in any case maybe a simple caching should do the trick

Comment: What i meant is that there are various files like js1,js2... all sums upto 70mb . So i will offer a zip folder to download and only link js1 or js2 file etc depending on the effects user wish to apply

Comment: Why would you need to download everything at once locally? Maybe you can load js1,js2 first as a default and then asynchronously load the rest of the files since they are not needed for the initial load but only on user click. If you include your scripts with the <script> tag normally your js should be getting cached on the browser